# Arrange marginal rug and density so they don't overlap with legend at bottom

Tags: r, ggplot2

Let's have a following dataframe:

```
test <- structure(list(category = c("C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", 
"C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", 
"C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", 
"C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", 
"C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", 
"C", "C", "C", "C"), position = c(43.87, 175.63, 119.58, 63.82, 
70.7, 87, 103.23, 128.84, 31.52, 99.21, 40.65, 27.44, 139.39, 
95.38, 87.56, 16.94, 45.18, 32.93, 62.68, 225.38, 48.85, 87.97, 
18.28, 82.39, 76.08, 23.91, 57.61, 76.3, 47.78, 108.4, 43.73, 
228.35, 71.39, 40.92, 59.93, 113.23, 29.51, 9.97, 134.46, 79.26, 
188.23, 24.96, 131.29, 52.58, 114.98, 100.4, 75.89, 54.44, 61.1, 
27.36, 26.95, 22.25, 62.63, 36.87, 15.19, 88.69, 28.92, 235.41, 
35.49, 46.76, 97.62, 47.67, 24.91), length = c(110.83, 205.63, 
135.97, 139.4, 137.48, 120.56, 131, 147.17, 90.37, 108.25, 141.27, 
154.22, 157.4, 143.66, 151.57, 185.03, 313.36, 60.45, 81.37, 
256.44, 140.56, 188.46, 100.16, 203.62, 172.79, 139.8, 174.39, 
132.27, 126.19, 129.12, 152.96, 294.5, 190.25, 112.24, 224.06, 
172.53, 308.87, 118.08, 168.83, 115.55, 238.9, 215.96, 159.52, 
88.47, 178.92, 178.92, 178.38, 81.43, 71.2, 125.03, 139.9, 93.25, 
144.58, 164.3, 126.32, 130.55, 102.31, 246.91, 136.16, 138.35, 
228.73, 124.76, 88.11)), row.names = c(NA, -63L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

**I would like to plot the variables as scatterplot, add rug on the y-axis and marginal distributions on both axes. I would also like to make the chart aesthetically pleasing.**

This is my most satisfying result so far:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggExtra)

plottest <- ggplot2::ggplot(test, aes(x=length, y=position, colour = category)) + 
  ggplot2::geom_point()+ ggplot2::geom_rug(sides = "r",
                                           col="steelblue",
                                           alpha=0.2, 
                                           size=1.5,
                                           outside = TRUE) + 
  ggplot2::theme_minimal() + 
  ggplot2::theme(legend.position="bottom",
                 axis.line.x = element_line(size = 0.45, color="#3a424f"),
                 axis.line.y = element_line(size = 0.45, color="#3a424f")) + 
  ggplot2::coord_cartesian(clip = "off") + 
  ggplot2::scale_color_manual(values=c("#174e73"))

ggExtra::ggMarginal(plottest, groupColour = TRUE)
```

And here is the result:

[image]

However I would prefer to have filled distributions and theme_bw() instead of theme_minimal(). However, in this case, the rug overlaps with distribution. This is not a big deal in case of this minimal example, however in my real-life data this can be more annoying.

**I am wondering how to plot rug on the outer side of the plot and move distribution a little bit away from the rug and plotting area, so the elements would not be cluttered one atop of another.**

This is another version of my code, with filled densities and preferred theme:

```
plottest <- ggplot2::ggplot(test, aes(x=length, y=position, colour = category)) + 
  ggplot2::geom_point()+ ggplot2::geom_rug(sides = "r",
                                           col="steelblue",
                                           alpha=0.2, 
                                           size=1.5,
                                           outside = TRUE) + 
  ggplot2::theme_bw() + 
  ggplot2::theme(legend.position="bottom") + 
  ggplot2::coord_cartesian(clip = "off") + 
  ggplot2::scale_color_manual(values=c("#174e73"))

ggExtra::ggMarginal(plottest, groupColour = TRUE,groupFill = TRUE)
```

This is what I produce with this code:
[image]

And this is what I would like to have (this graph is prepared in gimp):
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not trivial, as the position of your marginal plot is sort of "relatively hard coded" with `ggExtra:::addRightMargPlot` in the sense that it is adding an extra gtable column directly adjacent to the panel, but here three (relatively simple) workarounds.

1. **Figure 1**. My favourite: Add an "invisible" dupe y axis and make cheeky use of the common newbie "mistake" to remove titles with `""` (this is still drawing something, and it is in general better to use `NULL`, but not here!). You could then even add a margin to this invisible title, but this is not even necessary here.
2. **Figure 2**: You can play around with the size argument. This will change the plot appearance drastically and might not be what you want.
3. **Figure 3** (by far the easiest): You can simply accept to plot the rug "inside" which is not necessarily such a huge compromise in your visual.

```r
library(ggExtra)
library(ggplot2)

p <-
  ggplot(test, aes(x = length, y = position, colour = category)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_rug(
    sides = "r",
    col = "steelblue",
    alpha = 0.2,
    size = 1.5,
    outside = TRUE
  ) +
  coord_cartesian(clip = "off") +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("#174e73")) +
  ## add a second axis 
  ## use of the common title = "" newbie mistake to your advantage
  scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = dup_axis(name = "")) +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom",
        axis.line.x = element_line(size = 0.45, color = "#3a424f"),
        axis.line.y = element_line(size = 0.45, color = "#3a424f"),
        ## remove all stuff from your axis 
        axis.text.y.right = element_blank(), 
        axis.ticks.y.right = element_blank(), 
        axis.line.y.right = element_blank())
#> Warning: Using `size` aesthetic for lines was deprecated in ggplot2 3.4.0.
#> ℹ Please use `linewidth` instead.
#> Warning: The `size` argument of `element_line()` is deprecated as of ggplot2 3.4.0.
#> ℹ Please use the `linewidth` argument instead.

ggMarginal(p, groupFill = TRUE)
```

[image]

```r
plottest <-
  ggplot(test, aes(x = length, y = position, colour = category)) +
  geom_point() +
## I've removed geom_rug for the below
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(
    legend.position = "bottom",
    axis.line.x = element_line(size = 0.45, color = "#3a424f"),
    axis.line.y = element_line(size = 0.45, color = "#3a424f")
  ) +
  coord_cartesian(clip = "off") +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("#174e73"))
#> Warning: The `size` argument of `element_line()` is deprecated as of ggplot2 3.4.0.
#> ℹ Please use the `linewidth` argument instead.


## Option 2 - playing around with sizes
## p_outside is your original plot
p_outside <- plottest +
  geom_rug(
    sides = "r",
    col = "steelblue",
    alpha = 0.2,
    size = 1.5,
    outside = TRUE
  )
#> Warning: Using `size` aesthetic for lines was deprecated in ggplot2 3.4.0.
#> ℹ Please use `linewidth` instead.
ggMarginal(p_outside, size = 1, groupFill = TRUE)
```

[image]

```r
## Option 3 - don't plot the rug outside
## p_inside is your plot with outside argument removed
p_inside <- plottest +
  geom_rug(
    sides = "r",
    col = "steelblue",
    alpha = 0.2,
    size = 1.5,
  )

ggMarginal(p_inside, groupFill = TRUE)
```

[image]

Comment: Option 1 is the best. I also played with cowplot - it produces nicer densities, although I was unable to anchor density plots to the secondary axes or spacer, since it accepts only one-panel grobs. I'll stick to the first option. Great solution.

Comment: @ramen I was thinking about stitching plots too, and it is certainly possible - but, this would become a much more involved solution as per your thoughts